# Pandas/sklearn: Vectorize large number of LinearRegression calculations

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame where I need to calculate a large numbers of regression coefficients. Each calculation will be only two dimensional. The independent variable will be a `['Base']` which is the same for all cases. The dependent variable series is organized along columns in my  DataFrame.

This is easy to accomplish with a `for` loop but in my real life DataFrame I have thousands of columns on which to run the regression, so it takes forever. Is there a vectorized way to accomplish this?

Below is a MRE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import time

df_data = {
        'Base':np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000),
        'Adder':np.random.randint(-3, 3, 1000)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Thing1'] = df['Base'] * 3 + df['Adder']
df['Thing2'] = df['Base'] * 6 + df['Adder']
df['Thing3'] = df['Base'] * 12 + df['Adder']
df['Thing4'] = df['Base'] * 4 + df['Adder']
df['Thing5'] = df['Base'] * 2.67 + df['Adder']

things = ['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3', 'Thing4', 'Thing5']

for t in things:
    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    X, y = df['Base'].values.reshape(-1,1), df[t].values.reshape(-1,1)
    reg.fit(X, y)
    b = reg.coef_[0][0]
    result_df.loc[t, 'Beta'] = b

print(result_df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.polyfit` for linear regression:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.polyfit(df['Base'], df.filter(like='Thing'), deg=1)).T
```

Output:

```
           0            1
0   3.002379    -0.714256
1   6.002379    -0.714256
2   12.002379   -0.714256
3   4.002379    -0.714256
4   2.672379    -0.714256
```

Answer (score 1):

@Quang-Hoang 's idea of using df.filter solves the problem. If you really want to use sklearn, this also works:

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X = df['Base'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.filter(items=things).values
reg.fit(X, y)
result_df['Betas'] = reg.coef_
y_predict = reg.predict(X)
result_df['Rsq'] = r2_score(y, y_predict)
```